# How do we specify the client area size of a form in design mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a form in c#. I want to specify the "Client-Area" of the form in the designer.

The Size property sets the size of the complete form, including the NC area. Is there any way to set the client area size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the ClientSize property?  This property allows you to modify the size of the client area of the control.  Seems to be what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.clientsize.aspx

Comment: Though this property is not available in the designer, but it works when I set this property in the constructor.

Thanks anyways, it works!